# Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar color setup

Tags: android

When I use this theme everything is OK.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

But I wanted to use custom toolbar so I changed app theme to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

The problem is that background of app now has the same color as a toolbar.
Before this change it was white.

When I change android:windowBackground it's only apply to Navigation Drawer.
How to make background color (marked by red arrow) white again ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **background color from xml file**

and try this style for no actionbar

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/common_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing only colorPrimary.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```